# Forward events from a GenEvent server to my process in elixir otp

Tags: pid, elixir, erlang-otp

I have a GenEvent server and I would like to be able to add several processes that get forwarded events when I send event notifications to the main server.

I can create a forwarder module and pass it a pid to send the message too, but as it seams like it must be a common pattern I was wondering if there is a better way.

In the [GenEvent docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/GenEvent.html#types) the type for a handler is

```
handler :: atom | {atom, term} | {pid, reference}
```

When I try to add a handler of the last form to a GenEvent server I always get an error.

```
GenEvent.add_mon_handler(pid, {self, make_ref}, [])
{:error,
 {:badarg,
  [{:erlang, :apply, [#PID<0.59.0>, :init, [[]]], []},
   {GenEvent, :do_handler, 3, [file: 'lib/gen_event.ex', line: 990]},
   {GenEvent, :do_add_handler, 5, [file: 'lib/gen_event.ex', line: 947]},
   {GenEvent, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'lib/gen_event.ex', line: 608]},
   {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 240]}]}}
```

There is no further information in the elixir documentation on how to add a handler consisting of a pid and a reference. The [erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_event.html#add_handler-3) for gen_event only shows it using handlers of the form `atom` and `{atom, term}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documentation issue. The function `GenEvent.add_mon_handler/3` does not take a handler consisting of `{pid, ref}` anymore. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/gyVce092C7I